What is the actual relationship between partition coefficient (logP or clog P) and Retention factor (Rf) value?
I have been wondering for a long time if there is any software or website that can predict the Rf value of a molecule based on its molecular structure (more so, because I was unable to figure out which compound was which on a TLC plate bearing 16 spots) I found a few papers that employed machine learning of the large sample set of Rf values, but I couldn't find any reliable software to use it.
My primary query is How do we predict the Retention factor (Rf) value computationally?
In ChemDraw, one can compute log P, clogP and log S values based on the selected chemical structure. However, I couldn't find any explicit relation between the partition coefficient (log P) and the Retention factor(Rf) value.
I believe that the higher the log P value (or cLog P), the more hydrophobic the compound is and the higher the Rf value. Similarly, an inverse relationship can be set for log S value and Rf. I am looking for an equation that connects the Rf value with these computed values.
Edit:  GC-MS generates the Total Ion Chromatogram (TIC) of a sample. Is there a correspondence of TIC with Rf value and retention time given in TIC?

@Poutnik Thanks for the comment. I thought log P encompasses the intramolecular and intermolecular components. Could you please elaborate on how compounds having same log P value when eluted in same mobile phase have different Rf values?

Please don't include multiple disparate questions into one post. It looks like you crammed a separate question with your edit at the very end.

Moved my comments to the answer.

$R_\text{f}$ is a function of

logP
relative contributions of intermolecular interaction of different types (electron pair donor, e.p. acceptor, dipoles)
mobile phase composition
stationary phase choice
conditioning of the stationary phase

3 compounds, with the same logP parameter, and with all other factors the same, can have 3 different $R_\text{f}$. Similarly, in HPLC, the same logP does not mean the same elution time.

Mobile phases based on electrophilic solvents selectively prefer nucleophilic compounds, increasing their $R_\text{f}$ more than for others.
Nucleophilic solvents selectively prefer electrophilic compounds.
Solvents with prominent dipole-dipole interactions selectively prefer compounds interacting via dipole-dipole interactions.

This frequently leads to situations where $R_\text{f}$ order of compounds switches, depending on the mobile phase choice and differences in nature of compounds.
You can find more e.g. at chem.libretexts.org - 28.4: Partition Chromatography

You report a mixture of 16 spots on the plate, but don't state the eventual scale of operation (I presume running the TLC is to identify a good solvent system for a subsequent column chromatography on preparative scale).
If some of the components of your mixture are more similar to each other, than others, consider a sequential back extraction.  Presuming there is no derivatization during the extraction, the full sequence considers

strong acids transferred into the aqueous phase by an extraction with aqueous saturated $\ce{Na2CO3}$, and back extracted against concentrated aqueous HCl
weak acids neutralized with aqueous NaOH ($c \approx \pu{10 mass\%}$) and  protonated again with concentrated aqueous HCl
organic bases to be protonated HCl (of $c \approx \pu{10 vol\%}$), and back extracted with $\ce{NH4OH}$
while neutral compounds would remain unaffected in the mother liquor

With knowledge about the sample's composition you can shorten this sequence.  An extraction well done can simplify a lot the subsequent steps of additional purification (recrystallization, distillation, sublimation; the many types of chromatography) or render them no longer necessary (what is considered "pure enough" down the road?).  Don't cut on the time to let the phases separate again, and drying of the organic phase of the recovered back extracts, though.  See e.g., Zubrick's primer the resources page mentions for details like the selection of drying agents.

Chromatography

If theses fractions still contain many compounds according to TLC, check if they sustain the TLC by a 2D development of a sheet cut into a square: after development along one direction, and gentle drying of the plate, turn the plate by 90 degrees and develop a twice with the same eluent.  Fractions should appear only on the diagonal of the plate, or else reaction/decomposition on the plate could be at the origin of the many spots.  Don't forget that there are plats of (acidic, neutral, basic) forms of (silica, alumina; reverse phase) stationary phases.

Check primary the literature what material was used during the chromatography, seek analogue separations (e.g., CAMAG's database) which constitute a basis for algorithms like PRISMA implemented in the contemporary commercially available chromatography robots.  Liquid chromatography can be simulated as such (e.g., Perri), equally the selection of columns / replacement of solvents can be guided by computer programs (e.g., elutenttranslator)

Sometimes to run multiple sequential separations is good enough (for instance because results are delivered faster, and overall cheaper), then an extended (manual) method development (let alone machine learning).  Say you have a mixture of A, B, C, K, L, M, then this one is separated into A, B, C and K, L, M in the first run, with a the second chromatography to split only the group of A, B, C, an the third to separate K, L, M into its components.  Since each separation is set up differently (stationary as well as liquid phase), this allows $\Delta(\Delta{}R_f)$ otherwise not reasonably accessible in a single chromatographic separation.

TIC (for total ion current) is a method of detection of hyphenated GC-MS, like the FID (flame ionization detector) is a detector other GC use.  As "an eye" at the exit of the column, its work is unrelated to the separation (hopefully) provided by the chromatography and the $R_f$ value.  On the plate, the $R_f$ is the ratio of inches or centimeters, the GC/HPLC has no other measure than minutes to express basically the same thing.


Nyiredy, S. Planar Chromatographic Method Development Using the PRISMA Optimization System and Flow Charts. J. Chromatogr. Sci. 2002, 40 (10), 553–563. https://doi.org/10.1093/chromsci/40.10.553 (open access)
Laferriere-Holloway, T. S.; Rios, A.; Lu, Y.; Okoro, C. C.; Van Dam, R. M. A Rapid and Systematic Approach for the Optimization of Radio Thin-Layer Chromatography Resolution. J.Chromatogr. A 2023, 1687, 463656. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.chroma.2022.463656 (author's manusscript).
Perri, M. J. Online Data Generation in Quantitative Analysis: Excel Spreadsheets and an Online HPLC Simulator Using a Jupyter Notebook on the Chem Compute Web Site. J. Chem. Educ. 2020, 97 (9), 2950–2954. https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jchemed.0c00565 (page about the simulation on chemcompute.org)

While potentially useful information, this doesn't really answer or address the main thrust of this question. Rather than posting this as an answer to this question, I'd recommend making a new question (with a self-answer) which asks the question that this answer answers, and then just cross referencing that new question in this question's comments.
